# bundle install failing for 'letter-opener' gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to use Ryan Bates 'letter-opener' gem as described in Episode #104 (and in many other places on the web)  In every instance I have found, it appears that users are simply including the gem in their Gem file with the traditional ruby gems gemsource.  When I attempt this, rails fails to find the gem.  I must be doing something wrong, but what?

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
...
gem "letter-opener", group: :development
```

Then I type

```
$ bundle install
```

and I receive the following message:

> Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
>   Could not find gem 'letter-opener (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in > your Gemfile.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a common error to mistype a compound-word rubygem with an underscore ('_') instead of a hyphon ('-') or viceversa.

If you ever find this problem, you can go to http://rubygems.org, and search for the gem's name.

In this case, searching for letter opener [returns this result](http://rubygems.org/gems/letter_opener), which suggests that the gem is actually called `letter_opener`

Comment: Thank you for the search strategy suggestion too.  (But I cannot believe I stared at this line, and still missed the mistake!  thanks.)

Comment: I'm a victim of this issue frequently, there are even gem names that are separated by a space, but in rubygems their name is a complete word, etc. Your best bet is to search when you have doubts =). Glad I could help

Answer (score 4):

use `gem 'letter_opener'`instead of `gem 'letter-opener'`.